# Renaming columns according to a string in the rows of a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with hundreds of columns like the example below:

```
  1              12                             13                            14                  15
               
id=10    formatted_value=U$ 20.000    weighted_value=U$ 20000    person_name=Natys Person    query={'id':0,'name':'Robert'}
id=11    formatted_value=U$ 10.000    weighted_value=U$ 10000    person_name=Mike Tyson      query={'id':2,'name':'Roberta'}
id=12    formatted_value=U$ 18.000    weighted_value=U$ 10000    person_name=Mike Talbud     sometext
```

I want to perform an operation to rename these columns with the string tha comes before the `=` sign in each row and then delete the `string=`

All rows has this same pattern beginning with `string=`

The output should be:

```
   id          formatted_value    weighted_value    person_name     query                          
    10            U$ 20.000          U$ 20000         Natys Person  {'id':0,'name':'Robert'}    
    11            U$ 10.000          U$ 10000         Mike Tyson    {'id':0,'name':'Robert'}
    12            U$ 18.000          U$ 10000         Mike Talbud   sometext
```

Tried  some approachs but I failed to do it.

Comment: can you provide the output of `df.head().to_dict()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x:dict(list(x.str.split('='))),axis=1).to_list())

   id formatted_value weighted_value   person_name
0  10       U$ 20.000       U$ 20000  Natys Person
1  11       U$ 10.000       U$ 10000    Mike Tyson
```

with the dictionaries:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x:dict(list(x.str.split('='))),axis=1).to_list())

   id formatted_value weighted_value   person_name                      query
0  10       U$ 20.000       U$ 20000  Natys Person   {'id':0,'name':'Robert'}
1  11       U$ 10.000       U$ 10000    Mike Tyson  {'id':2,'name':'Roberta'}
```

where

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': {0: 'id=10', 1: 'id=11'},
 '12': {0: 'formatted_value=U$ 20.000', 1: 'formatted_value=U$ 10.000'},
 '13': {0: 'weighted_value=U$ 20000', 1: 'weighted_value=U$ 10000'},
 '14': {0: 'person_name=Natys Person', 1: 'person_name=Mike Tyson'},
 '15': {0: "query={'id':0,'name':'Robert'}",
  1: "query={'id':2,'name':'Roberta'}"}})
```

### EDIT:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x:dict(list(x.str.replace('(^[^=]+$)', 'one_text=\\1', regex=True).str.split('='))),axis=1).to_list())
 
   id formatted_value  ...                      query  one_text
0  10       U$ 20.000  ...   {'id':0,'name':'Robert'}       NaN
1  11       U$ 10.000  ...  {'id':2,'name':'Roberta'}       NaN
2  12       U$ 18.000  ...                        NaN  sometext
```

Comment: @merchmallow the code runs on the example you gave!

Comment: I know.  But it failed, then I check all the columns ( there 345) and found 2 of them ewith dict like format so I updated the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @merchmallow the code runs in the updated version also. The version that has dictionaries. There must be another reason as to why the code is not running on the whole dataset but not because of the dictionaries

Comment: @merchmallow Note that those are not dictionaries but rather strings. Please provide the data for the example you are using eg.paste the output of  `example.to_dict()` in your question

Comment: I found the problem: some rows has only a string with  no `=` sign and then we got the error.  Is there a way to add a try/except to leave these rows as it is? This is not happening in the first row tho

Comment: @merchmallow now that definitely cause the error. Do you want to drop the whole row or just those specific values?

Comment: @merchmallow add a row that has that issue to your data above.

Comment: Done! added a row with no `=` sign

Comment: @merchmallow and how do you decide that it is under `query`?

Comment: whatever the row has: if its `someetxt` then leave it `someetxt`

Comment: @merchmallow but you placed it under `query`. Should it not be under a new column sometext? ie its either you remove them or place them in a completely new column. There is no way they can be in the column so far given

Comment: I just wanted to tell you that some rows are wrongly filled with strings not showing the pattern `=`

Comment: @merchmallow I can see that. The problem is where do you want them in the final data? ie since they are not id/formatted_value/weighted_value/person_name/query. Where do you want them to be? on a new column? or drop them?

Comment: I dont want to drop the row, cant we just leave it NaN then?

Answer (score 1):

Using a `stack`/`extract`/`unstack` vectorial approach:

```
out = (df
  .stack().droplevel(1)
  .str.extract('([^=]+)=\s*(.*)')
  .set_index(0, append=True)[1]
  .unstack().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

output:

```
  formatted_value  id   person_name                      query weighted_value
0       U$ 20.000  10  Natys Person   {'id':0,'name':'Robert'}       U$ 20000
1       U$ 10.000  11    Mike Tyson  {'id':2,'name':'Roberta'}       U$ 10000
```

##### handling duplicate index

we can reset the index and restore it later:

```
out = (df
  .reset_index(drop=True)
  .stack().droplevel(1)
  .str.extract('([^=]+)=\s*(.*)')
  .set_index(0, append=True)[1]
  .unstack().rename_axis(columns=None)
  .set_axis(df.index)
)
```

Comment: It gives me this error msg: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: Can you provide your example as DataFrame constructor? Do you need to keep the index?

Answer (score 0):

You can try split the value into dict and convert each dictionary column to separate column

```py
df = df.applymap(lambda x: dict([x.split('=')]))
out = pd.concat([df[col].apply(pd.Series) for col in df.columns], axis=1)
```

```
print(out)

   id formatted_value weighted_value   person_name
0  10       U$ 20.000       U$ 20000  Natys Person
1  11       U$ 10.000       U$ 10000    Mike Tyson
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess in some columns containing more than 1 `=`, so try this solution

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': {0: 'id=10', 1: 'id=11'},
 '12': {0: 'formatted_value=U$ 20.000', 1: 'formatted_value=U$ 10.000'},
 '13': {0: 'weighted_value=U$ 20000', 1: 'weighted_value=U$ 10000'},
 '14': {0: 'person_name=Natys Person', 1: 'person_name=Mike Tyson'},
 '15': {0: "query={'id':0,'name':'Robert'}",
  1: "query={'id':2,'name':'Roberta'}"}})

for column in df.columns:
    sample_value = df.loc[0,column]
    new_column_name = sample_value.split("=")[0]
    df.rename(columns={column: new_column_name}, inplace=True)
    df.loc[:, new_column_name] = df[new_column_name].apply(lambda x: "=".join(x.split("=")[1:]))
df
```